# google spreadsheet search from textfinder and return to HTML

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Id like search by textFinder and return it to an array for html table. I have multiple spreadsheets and my intention is to retrieve spreadsheets data from one text input using textFinder then send them to a HTML page(using google [HTML templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)).

I have tried with the below codes but couldn't find a solution please help.

**Code.gs**

```js
function doGet(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  var output = html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return output;

}
function getFilter(search){

  var ssID = "Sheet ID",
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[2];
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  var ranges = [];
    if ("name" in search && search.name != "") {
      ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 4, Alast - 1, 3).createTextFinder(search.name).findAll();
    }
    if ("ac" in search && search.ac != "") {
      var acRanges = sheet.getRange(2, 3, Alast - 1, 1).createTextFinder(search.ac).findAll();
    if (ranges.length > 0) {
      ranges = ranges.filter(function(r1) {return acRanges.some(function(r2) {return r1.getRow() == r2.getRow()})});
    } else {
      ranges = acRanges;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

      var row = ranges[i].getRow();
      var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getDisplayValues(); //get all values for the row

    return values;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function setPageValues () {
      var search = document.getElementsByName('searchtext')[0].value;
      var ac = document.getElementsByName('ac')[0].value;
      var obj = {};
      if (!search && !ac) alert("No search values.");
      if (search) {
        obj.name = search;
      }
      if (ac) {
        obj.ac= ac;
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(disp).getFilter(obj);
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="ac">
<input type="text" name="searchtext">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="setPageValues();">
<br /><br />
<div name="resultbox">
    <? var values = getFilter(); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= values[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a `doGet()` function in your `code.gs` file?

Comment: Yes, i made a index for html service.

Comment: Cool, can you please show your doGet() function? Also, can you explain what you are seeing if it isn't working as-is?

Comment: I added doGet() script. When it published the error message comes 'TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'name' in undefined'.

Comment: You are calling `getFilter()` without passing a variable on the line `<? var values = getFilter(); ?>` in you HTML file. This means that when `getFilter()` is called, the variable `search` is undefined and you can not use the `in` operator on it.

Comment: Rafa GUillermo// Could you please let me know how to implement in this case if there is any way to  search text and make tables. I know google table chart but it cannot load multiple tables in a single html.